# Isolated scope binding types

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-directive, angular-components, isolate-scope

According to [AngularJS Developer Guide - Directives "Isolating the Scope of a Directive"](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#isolating-the-scope-of-a-directive),  scope binding can be done in 3 types

`=`, `@` and `&`

and

according to ["Directive Definition Object" section in this Page](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile), scope binding can be done in 4 types

`=`, `@`, `&` and **`<`**

Even in most of the online articles isolated scope binding is given of 3 types only.

Which is correct?

Comment: One-way `<` binding was added with AngularJS V1.5. See [AngularJS commit feat($compile): add one-way binding to the isolate scope definition](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/4ac23c0ac59c269d65b7f78efec75d060121bd18)

Comment: The Developer Guide section that you quoted is dated. For a more up-to-date guide to isolate scope, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - Component Based Application Architecture](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#component-based-application-architecture)

Answer (score 5):

these are the standard bindings before angular 1.5

```
=, @ and &
```

from angular 1.5 onwards with the new concept of component based architecture it has been introduced this binding

```
<
```

that represents a single way binding.

Answer (score 2):

We are create custom directive by using `=, @ and &`.

Later angular 1.5 : Angularjs introduced Component is a special kind of directive that uses a simpler configuration which is suitable for a component-based application structure.

The `<` symbol denotes one-way bindings which are available since 1.5. The difference to = is that the bound properties in the component scope are not watched, which means if you assign a new value to the property in the component scope, it will not update the parent scope.

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component

Answer (score 0):

i think there is 3 types:

the **=** for a bidirectional binding (for ex Parent Directive share a property with its child)

the **@** for one direction binding (for ex Parent Directive send a params to its child)

the **&** for function binding (for ex a child can call a function declared in the scope of his Parent Directive)